# Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, classpath

I have a Spring + Maven project which I wanted to run on Tomcat 7.0.69. 
When I do it by script everything works fine. Here is prepare script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

PROFILE=$1
CONFIG_REPO=../../configuration
DEPLOY_DIR=tomcat-deploy
WAR_PREFIX=ppp-web/
WAR_NAME=ppp$(echo $PROFILE | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]').war

validate_profile() {
    if [[ $PROFILE != 'AS' && $PROFILE != 'TN' && $PROFILE != 'HS' ]]; then
        echo "Incorrect application profile chosen: $PROFILE. Use TN, AS or HS."
        exit 1
    fi
}

validate_environment_settings() {
    if [[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[1;31m"
        echo -e "ERROR: ***************************************************************************************"
        echo -e "ERROR: *** You must set CATALINA_HOME environment variable before trying to deploy Tomcat. ***"
        echo -e "ERROR: ***************************************************************************************"
        echo -e "\e[0m"
        exit 1
    fi
}

setup_deploy_dir () {
    echo "Setting up deploy directory $DEPLOY_DIR ..."

    rm -rf $DEPLOY_DIR

    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/bin
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/conf
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/lib
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/logs
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/temp
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/webapps
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/webapps-conf
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/webapps-lib
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR/work

    cp $CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar $DEPLOY_DIR/bin/
}

copy_if_exists () {
    local src=$1
    local dest=$2

    if [[ -e $src ]]; then
        echo "-> Copying file $src to $dest ..."
        cp -r $src $dest
    else
        echo "-> Directory or file $src does not exist. Skipped."
    fi
}

copy_to_correct_directories () {
    local src=$1
    local f
    for f in $src/*; do
        if [[ $f == */conf ||\
              $f == */webapps-conf ||\
              $f == */bin ||\
              $f == */install-additional-libs.xml ]]; then
            copy_if_exists $f $DEPLOY_DIR
        else
            # any other file is copied to application configuration directory
            copy_if_exists $f $DEPLOY_DIR/webapps-conf
        fi
    done
}

prepare_configuration () {
    local app=$1
    local env=$2
    local box=$3
    local instance=$4

    echo "Preparing configuration ..."

    copy_to_correct_directories $CONFIG_REPO/common $DEPLOY_DIR
    copy_to_correct_directories $CONFIG_REPO/$app/common $DEPLOY_DIR
    copy_to_correct_directories $CONFIG_REPO/$app/$env/common $DEPLOY_DIR
    copy_to_correct_directories $CONFIG_REPO/$app/$env/$box/common $DEPLOY_DIR
    copy_to_correct_directories $CONFIG_REPO/$app/$env/$box/$instance $DEPLOY_DIR
}

create_instance_name () {
    local instance=$1
    echo "Creating instance.name.properties file ..."
    echo "instance.name = $instance" > $DEPLOY_DIR/webapps-conf/instance.name.properties
}

install_additional_libs () {
    echo "Installing additional libs ..."
    mvn -f $DEPLOY_DIR/install-additional-libs.xml dependency:copy
}

copy_war () {
    echo "Copying $WAR_NAME ..."
    cp ${WAR_PREFIX}target/$WAR_NAME $DEPLOY_DIR/webapps/
}

validate_profile
validate_environment_settings
setup_deploy_dir
prepare_configuration PPP-${PROFILE} LOCAL localhost PPP${PROFILE}-LOCAL
create_instance_name PPP${PROFILE}-LOCAL
install_additional_libs
copy_war
```

and here is my run script:

```
#!/bin/bash

validate_environment_settings() {
    if [[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ]]; then
        echo -e "\e[1;31m"
        echo -e "ERROR: ***************************************************************************************"
        echo -e "ERROR: *** You must set CATALINA_HOME environment variable before trying to deploy Tomcat. ***"
        echo -e "ERROR: ***************************************************************************************"
        echo -e "\e[0m"
        exit 1
    fi
}

start_tomcat_windows() {
    cmd /Q << EOF
set CATALINA_BASE=%cd%\\tomcat-deploy
%CATALINA_HOME%\\bin\\startup.bat
EOF
}

start_tomcat_unix() {
    export CATALINA_BASE=$(pwd)/tomcat-deploy
    $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
}

start_tomcat() {
    local system=$(uname -s)

    case $system in
        MINGW*)
            start_tomcat_windows
            ;;

        Linux|CYGWIN*)
            start_tomcat_unix
            ;;

        *)
            echo "Unsupported system: $system"
            exit 1
    esac
}

validate_environment_settings
start_tomcat
```

As I said before when I do it from cmd everything works fine. But when I'm trying to run it from IntelliJ Idea 2016.2 I'm getting error:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [eps.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

File eps.properties is under PROJECT\profiles-ppp\tomcat-deploy\webapps-conf.

The reference to it is in applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:eps.properties,classpath:ppp-mom.properties,classpath*:*instance.name.properties,classpath:ppp.db.properties"/>
```

The VM options are:

```
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doin wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most probably the directory PROJECT\profiles-ppp\tomcat-deploy\webapps-conf is not in the classpath.
Usually in tomcat classpath contains : ${yourwar}/WEB-INF/classes,${yourwar}/WEB-INF/lib, plus the common/classes  common/lib or shared/classes , shared/lib, (plus the tomcat server libs). 
The common and shared directories are not always added to classapth, so it has to be verified in the scripts.

Comment: I got it, but how can I add it in IntelliJ? It is this Spring classpath.